# How do I input these interval equation in to wolfram to show me the solution

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

How do I enter these equation into wolfram to show me the interval type equation which gives the solution as exact values..

Question 1 :
$2\tan x\cos x = \tan x$ where $0\leq x< 2\pi$

Question 2: 
$2{\sin ^2}x-\sin x - 1 = 0$ where $0\leq x< 2\pi$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2+tanx+cosx+-+tanx+%3D+0+

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Trigonometry.html

Answer (score 3):

The key word seems to be "over"...

[solve 2 tanx cosx - tanx = 0 over $0<x<2$pi](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202%20tanx%20cosx%20-%20tanx%20=%200%20over%200%3Cx%3C2pi)

[solve 2sin^2(x)-sin(x)-1=0 over $0<x<2$pi](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202sin%5E2%28x%29-sin%28x%29-1=0%20over%200%3Cx%3C2pi)

Comment: are you postive?

Comment: because when I enter solve 2 tanx cosx - tanx = 0 over 0
 I get no solution???

Comment: Sorry. The editor ate some of my characters ("<" interfering with HTML code).

Comment: "on" and "for" also work.  You can get a little fancier, too, like "over the domain" but concise is certainly good.

Comment: how can I make it show me step by step algebraically

Comment: I'm not sure it will do that for you (in a restricted domain). However, the link Amzoti posted in the comments above: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2+tanx+cosx+-+tanx+%3D+0+ (solving without restriction) has a link to a "step-by-step" solution. You could follow that and then impose your restriction as a final step.